# Keep the selection after filtering a QTableView with a QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt4, qtableview

I created a `QTableView` linked to a `QSortFilterProxyModel` linked to another model.
Under the `QTableView` (in the GUI) there is a `QLineEdit` used for "searching" an element in the view.

My idea is to write in the `QLineEdit` what I'm looking for and let the view show only the matched elements. After filtering, I want to select the concerned item and then clean the `QLineEdit` for returning at the complete view.
Everything works but the selected item that will be filtered will also lose the selection because of the invalidation.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remember the selected rows before the filtering and then just restore it when you're done with filtering.

You could use the `QItemSelectionModel` directly I'd imagine.

Use `QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows()` before filtering and select rows after filtering using `QItemSelectionModel::select()`.

I know this thread is very old, but I thought I'd leave the comment for anybody else facing a similar problem.

Comment: selectRows() returns QModelIndexList, which cannot be used with select(). But you can use QItemSelectionModel::selection() which returns QItemSelection, which can be used in QItemSelectionModel::select().

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote it looks like the problem is in the `QTableView` loosing selection when you're cleaning your `QLineEdit` content. If you're starting your *'search'* routine in the line edit's [editingFinished()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) or [textChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlineedit.html#textChanged) signals you can [disconnect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#disconnect) from them before changing the `QLineEdit` and then reconnect back again. Or use a boolean flag and don't change filtering when it's on. It would be much easier to answer your question if you would post up a simplified version of your code with the problem you're having.

Comment: If i select an item and return to the complete view it will keep the selection, but if in the complete view i select an item and then i filter the view excluding that item, it will lose the selection.